# knockoutjs: I'm trying to add a boolean variable to an ObservableArray

Tags: knockout.js

I'm trying to add a boolean value to my ObservableArray in knockoutjs to check if I've edited my object. The goal is when I click save all, only the data that has been modified gets send to the back end for updating. If the value is false, skip the object, if it's true send it for updating.

The code I'm trying to use to initialize this:

```
var self = this;
//S1:Boolean to check wheather the operation is for Edit and New Record
var IsNewRecord = false;

self.WorkOrders = ko.observableArray([]);

loadWorkOrders();
//tried adding the value to the existing array by looping through each object, 
// if I remove this, the code loads the data properly and works as it should,
// without the check if the objects have been edited.
ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.WorkOrders(), function (i) {
    i.Edited = false
})


//S2:Method to Load all WorkOrders by making call to WEB API GET method
function loadWorkOrders() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/api/WorkOrderAPI",
        success: function (data) {
            self.WorkOrders(data);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert(err.status + " from first get, are you connected to VPN?");
        }
    });
};
```

In this code I've used

```
ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.WorkOrders(), function (i) {
    i.Edited = false
})
```

In an attempt to add the Edited value to the array. I think the error is actually that I have to make a new array using the current one and adding the value Edited to each object in the array...

An alternative solution could be to add the variable on the server end, though I'd think that wouldn't be the most "correct" solution. To query the data I'm using:

```
    // GET api/TimeRegistrationAPI
    public IQueryable<TimeRegistration> GetTimeRegistration()
    {
        return db.TimeRegistration;
    }
```

Looking through the Knockout documentation I couldn't really find the proper way to solve this (ref. http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html)

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have asynchronous load so at the point where you do `ko.utils.arrayForEach(...)` the array is still empty. To fix that you need to return the promise from `loadWorkOrders`:

```
function loadWorkOrders() {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/api/WorkOrderAPI",
        success: function (data) {
            self.WorkOrders(data);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert(err.status + " from first get, are you connected to VPN?");
        }
    });
};
```

and then iterate your array in `then` callback:

```
loadWorkOrders().then(function() {
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.WorkOrders(), function (i) {
        i.Edited = false
    });
});
```